# Strategy for rendering the same sprites many times without slowing down FPS

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am trying to generate a game involving a labyrinth, generated at random for each level. I am designing this game for android and am using openGL 1.

FPS is around 60 when I am running fairly small labyrinths, but when I start to go high in numbers the FPS drops down to 30's-40's.
I draw each wall as a separate sprite (using a standard spriteBatcher I got off the internet, and the same Texture) and FPS drops when the number of sprites is about 500 or more. FPS doesn't seem to go further down when I got up to 3000 sprites, but it does go back up to ~60 when I zoom in.
So I figured that the number of sprites that have to be displayed is the reason for the slowdown.

My initial strategy was to draw the labyrinth upon initiation, and then render it as one sprite. However, I will be making in-game changes to the labyrinth occasionally, so this drawing will be invoked during game-time, and has to be fairly fast.
I tried grabbing the pixels off the display and also tried to draw the labyrinth using Canvas in the background but both methods take about 1 full second.

I will appreciate any idea on how to get around this, and any thought on why the game slows down if my hypothesis is wrong.

Thank you

Disclaimer - I am not a very experienced programmer.

Comment: Are you programming your game in Android Studio? Unreal? Unity?

Comment: No, I'm writing in Eclipse and I wrote all the wrapper code (with help from internet)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot experience in Android system or OpenGL ES.

But, to have a better performance in OpenGL you should do a minimal :

1. Different binding (buffer, textures, ...)
2. Don't use a lot of draw call (batching is the best)

To don't have to bind several buffer, the better way is to use one and only one "big" vbo that you bound at the start of rendering.
For the textures, there is a lot of way. Since you are targeting OpenGL 1, the better way should be to use one big texture array.

To perform batching, you should (and must) use glMultiDrawElements (or Array, but elements is preferred for caching).

So, for your problem, I will try to do a lot of things by myself. You can't use sparse bindless textures (and it should be the better solution for you), but you can use texture array (if it is available in the version you are targeting, I am not sure about it).

If you can't use texture array, you could allocate one and only one big texture, and put inside a lot of sprites, for example, you could put inside 20 or 30 sprites, adjust the UVs in consequences.After, you perform a loop of glDrawMultiElements :).

In pseudo code, your render loop should be like this

```
for each batch of (say 30 sprites)
    glBindTexture();
    glMultiDrawElements(); // maybe 300 commands (if a sprite is used for 10 walls)
end for
```

Comment: Actually, I only call the draw command once, and I use a single texture.
I am not an expert either, so part of what you mention I am not 100% sure of, but I think that my batcher does everything that you mention.
I did however notice today that sometimes zooming out also helps, so I am starting to think that the slowdown is due to the blending scheme, and that it is very sensitive to the exact pixel position when the sprite sizes are being changed. I will try to remove the blending to see